# Cannot install RHIPE. error: unable to load shared object

Tags: r, hadoop

I am trying to install RHIPE for R, following this instruction:

https://www.datadr.org/install.html

I have finished everything successfully, EXCEPT the last step: installing RHIPE. I have set all the environment variables as instructed. And I even set LD_LIBRARY_PATH by editing the .bashrc file in the HOME folder. I can run and get (even after restarting the terminal):

```
$echo "$LD_LIBRARY_PATH"
/home/cluster1/users/user/R/lib64/R/lib
```

But when I try to install the RHIPE.tar.gz. I will get the following error message. It seems like the R CMD INSTALL RHIPE.tar.gz is pointing to an unknow R folder (correct?). I have searched several websites, but people posted the same issue are still waiting for answers. So I bring up this topic again on Stack Overflow. Please help! Thanks.

```
* installing to library â/home/cluster1/R/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu-library/2.15â
* installing *source* package âRhipeâ ...
** libs
g++ -I/home/cluster1/users/User/R/lib64/R/include -DNDEBUG  -I/usr/local/include    -fpic  -g -O2  -I.  -g -O2  -DUSEAUTOSHORT -DHAVE_UINTPTR_T    `/home/cluster1/users/User/R/lib64/R/bin/R CMD config --cppflags` `pkg-config --cflags protobuf` -c rexp.pb.cc -o rexp.pb.o
g++ -I/home/cluster1/users/User/R/lib64/R/include -DNDEBUG  -I/usr/local/include    -fpic  -g -O2  -I.  -g -O2  -DUSEAUTOSHORT -DHAVE_UINTPTR_T    `/home/cluster1/users/User/R/lib64/R/bin/R CMD config --cppflags` `pkg-config --cflags protobuf` -c message.cc -o message.o
g++ -I/home/cluster1/users/User/R/lib64/R/include -DNDEBUG  -I/usr/local/include    -fpic  -g -O2  -I.  -g -O2  -DUSEAUTOSHORT -DHAVE_UINTPTR_T    `/home/cluster1/users/User/R/lib64/R/bin/R CMD config --cppflags` `pkg-config --cflags protobuf` -c fileio.cc -o fileio.o
g++ -I/home/cluster1/users/User/R/lib64/R/include -DNDEBUG  -I/usr/local/include    -fpic  -g -O2  -I.  -g -O2  -DUSEAUTOSHORT -DHAVE_UINTPTR_T    `/home/cluster1/users/User/R/lib64/R/bin/R CMD config --cppflags` `pkg-config --cflags protobuf` -c signal.cc -o signal.o
g++ -I/home/cluster1/users/User/R/lib64/R/include -DNDEBUG  -I/usr/local/include    -fpic  -g -O2  -I.  -g -O2  -DUSEAUTOSHORT -DHAVE_UINTPTR_T    `/home/cluster1/users/User/R/lib64/R/bin/R CMD config --cppflags` `pkg-config --cflags protobuf` -c display.cc -o display.o
g++ -I/home/cluster1/users/User/R/lib64/R/include -DNDEBUG  -I/usr/local/include    -fpic  -g -O2  -I.  -g -O2  -DUSEAUTOSHORT -DHAVE_UINTPTR_T    `/home/cluster1/users/User/R/lib64/R/bin/R CMD config --cppflags` `pkg-config --cflags protobuf` -c reducer.cc -o reducer.o
g++ -I/home/cluster1/users/User/R/lib64/R/include -DNDEBUG  -I/usr/local/include    -fpic  -g -O2  -I.  -g -O2  -DUSEAUTOSHORT -DHAVE_UINTPTR_T    `/home/cluster1/users/User/R/lib64/R/bin/R CMD config --cppflags` `pkg-config --cflags protobuf` -c mapper.cc -o mapper.o
g++ -I/home/cluster1/users/User/R/lib64/R/include -DNDEBUG  -I/usr/local/include    -fpic  -g -O2  -I.  -g -O2  -DUSEAUTOSHORT -DHAVE_UINTPTR_T    `/home/cluster1/users/User/R/lib64/R/bin/R CMD config --cppflags` `pkg-config --cflags protobuf` -c mapreduce.cc -o mapreduce.o
g++ -I/home/cluster1/users/User/R/lib64/R/include -DNDEBUG  -I/usr/local/include    -fpic  -g -O2  -I.  -g -O2  -DUSEAUTOSHORT -DHAVE_UINTPTR_T    `/home/cluster1/users/User/R/lib64/R/bin/R CMD config --cppflags` `pkg-config --cflags protobuf` -c main.cc -o main.o
g++  rexp.pb.o message.o fileio.o signal.o display.o reducer.o mapper.o mapreduce.o main.o -o ../inst/bin/RhipeMapReduce -I.  -g -O2  -DUSEAUTOSHORT -DHAVE_UINTPTR_T    `/home/cluster1/users/User/R/lib64/R/bin/R CMD config --cppflags` `pkg-config --cflags protobuf` -fpic `/home/cluster1/users/User/R/lib64/R/bin/R CMD config --ldflags` `pkg-config --libs protobuf`  `/home/cluster1/users/User/R/lib64/R/bin/R CMD config --cppflags` `/home/cluster1/users/User/R/lib64/R/bin/R CMD config --ldflags`
chmod 755 ../inst/bin/RhipeMapReduce
g++ -I/home/cluster1/users/User/R/lib64/R/include -DNDEBUG  -I/usr/local/include    -fpic  -g -O2  -I.  -g -O2  -DUSEAUTOSHORT -DHAVE_UINTPTR_T    `/home/cluster1/users/User/R/lib64/R/bin/R CMD config --cppflags` `pkg-config --cflags protobuf` -c serverbridge.cc -o serverbridge.o
g++ -I/home/cluster1/users/User/R/lib64/R/include -DNDEBUG  -I/usr/local/include    -fpic  -g -O2  -I.  -g -O2  -DUSEAUTOSHORT -DHAVE_UINTPTR_T    `/home/cluster1/users/User/R/lib64/R/bin/R CMD config --cppflags` `pkg-config --cflags protobuf` -c rhooks.cc -o rhooks.o
rhooks.cc: In function âSEXPREC* unserializeUsingPB(SEXPREC*)â:
rhooks.cc:59: warning: integer overflow in expression
g++ -I/home/cluster1/users/User/R/lib64/R/include -DNDEBUG  -I/usr/local/include    -fpic  -g -O2  -I.  -g -O2  -DUSEAUTOSHORT -DHAVE_UINTPTR_T    `/home/cluster1/users/User/R/lib64/R/bin/R CMD config --cppflags` `pkg-config --cflags protobuf` -c md5.c -o md5.o
g++ rexp.pb.o message.o serverbridge.o fileio.o rhooks.o md5.o -o Rhipe.so  -shared -I.  -g -O2  -DUSEAUTOSHORT -DHAVE_UINTPTR_T    `/home/cluster1/users/User/R/lib64/R/bin/R CMD config --cppflags` `pkg-config --cflags protobuf` -fpic `/home/cluster1/users/User/R/lib64/R/bin/R CMD config --ldflags` `pkg-config --libs protobuf`  `/home/cluster1/users/User/R/lib64/R/bin/R CMD config --cppflags` `/home/cluster1/users/User/R/lib64/R/bin/R CMD config --ldflags`
installing to /home/cluster1/R/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu-library/2.15/Rhipe/libs
** R
** inst
** preparing package for lazy loading
** help
*** installing help indices
** building package indices
** testing if installed package can be loaded
**Error : .onLoad failed in loadNamespace() for 'Rhipe', details:
call: dyn.load(file, DLLpath = DLLpath, ...)
error: unable to load shared object '/home/cluster1/R/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu-library/2.15/Rhipe/libs/Rhipe.so':
libprotobuf.so.7: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
Error: loading failed
Execution halted
ERROR: loading failed**
* removing â/home/cluster1/R/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu-library/2.15/Rhipeâ
```

Comment: It seems like the installation cannot find the rhipe.so file. Where to download the rhipe.so file? Can we extract the rhipe.7.31.tar.gz to get the rhipe.so file? Please help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution! The instruction from

https://www.datadr.org/install.html

is wrong.

I found this one instead:

https://github.com/tesseradata/RHIPE/

Set the LD_LIBRARY_PATH to where you installed Protobuf, point it to ../protobuf/lib, then it would work.

Comment: The current Rhipe.0.73 r-package is incompatible with the lastest Cloudera Hadoop (CDH5). You will still get error even though you have successfully installed Rhipe0.73. I tried to downgrade to CDH4.7, and now the R/Cloudera Hadoop is working fine! (Just keep in mind that CDH does not come with production ready Yarn)